# Did Tyrion use all the Wildfire?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

A ways back now, during the War of the Five Kings, Stannis tried to take Kings Landing by invading through Blackwater Bay. This plan was foiled by Tyrion finding out about the [caches of wildfire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wildfire_plot) underneath the city and using them to burn Stannis' fleet.

**Did Tyrion use the entire cache of [wildfire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wildfire) for this event?**

Reason for asking:

> Cersei will not be able to have a trial by combat, so she needs a way out. One theory is that she will burn down the Great Sept.  In the books Cersei burns down the Tower of the Hand, so there is precedence for her burning buildings. This plan would need the wildfire to work, and that could have been the "rumor" Qyburn was looking into...

Answers from the show or books are welcome.

Comment: But did he [*start* the fire](https://youtu.be/eFTLKWw542g)?

Comment: Called it, correct on every point. Excellent work.

Comment: Not [quite](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Destruction_of_the_Great_Sept_of_Baelor?file=610_Sept_of_Baelor_Destruction_Promo.png) all of it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

First of all we need to understand what was the extent of the said [plot](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wildfire_plot).

[Aerys II](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aerys_II_Targaryen) had placed wildfire caches on all key positions of the city which primarily included the city gates, Red Keep, Great Sept of Baelor and Dragonpit.

No one except chosen members of the Pyromancers, King Aerys & Jaime Lannister knew about it. [Lord Chelsted](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Qarlton_Chelsted) came to suspect the plot and was burnt for trying to dissuade Aerys from using it.

Jaime later killed Aerys, [Rosart](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rossart), [Garigus](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Garigus), [Belis](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Belis) and other pyromancers involved in the plot but he never asked them about the locations of the said caches.

From ASOS:

> “When I came on **Rossart**, he was dressed as a common man-at-arms,
>   hurrying to a postern gate. **I slew him first**. **Then I slew
>   Aerys**, before he could find someone else to carry his message to the
>   pyromancers. **Days later, I hunted down the others and slew them as
>   well**. Belis offered me gold, and Garigus wept for mercy. Well, a
>   sword’s more merciful than fire, but I don’t think Garigus much
>   appreciated the kindness I showed him.”

This means among the living people, except Jaime and Brienne no one has a clue about this last madness of King Aerys.

Later, Tyrion found out only the cache beneath the dragonpit. That means, the other caches are still soundly in place.

From ACOK:

> “This cannot be true,” said Tyrion as he pored over the ledgers.
>   “**Almost thirteen thousand jars?** Do you take me for a fool? I’m not
>   about to pay the king’s gold for empty jars and pots of sewage sealed
>   with wax, I warn you.”
>
> “No, no,” Hallyne squeaked, “the sums are accurate, I swear. We have
>   been, hmmm, most fortunate, my lord Hand. **Another cache of Lord
>   Rossart’s was found, more than three hundred jars. Under the
>   Dragonpit!** Some whores have been using the ruins to entertain their
>   patrons, and one of them fell through a patch of rotted floor into a
>   cellar. When he felt the jars, he mistook them for wine. He was so
>   drunk he broke the seal and drank some.”

But this quote uses the word **another**. Which means some of the caches were discovered previously, of which we do not know about. Nevertheless, it is safe to assume that most of the caches will be intact.

Other than that, there is also another intriguing thing. How much did Varys know? His little birds must have observed pyromancers coming and going. If that was enough to make a man like Lord Chelsted suspicious, surely Varys must have been so as well. Later, we know Varys knows many of the secrets of the red keep including secret passages. He might have discovered some of those caches beneath the palace himself.

Comment: Note that this is a book answer; the show has played fast and loose with the wildfire data.

Comment: My argument against this would be that Tyrion commissioned the pyromancers to make more (show).  That and the Stannis' siege was a desperate affair (both).  One would assume that all the ammunition was expended to prevent such a thing.

Comment: Why does Brienne know?

Comment: Ah I see from another question that Brienne and Jamie have discussed his reasons for killing the mad king

Comment: @PeteB. Tyrion did command Pyromancers to build more wildfire in both books and show but Idk which cache did Tyrion find by chance. It is unlikely that he found all of them but there is no doubt that they must have nearly exhausted their stockpile against Stannis

Comment: @Toby You are correct, Jaime told Brienne about real story of Fall of KL. Which is how Brienne came to respect him and have fond feelings from him unlike other people. She understood his reasons and respected him for sacrificing his honor to save the people.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yup you are missing the fact that 12,700 jars are produced by the pyromancers on orders of Cersei Lannister, not found as old hidden caches. **They only found one cache of Aerys, rest were mass produced by Cersei's orders**. No one found other caches that we know of but we do know that they are all over the city. The 300 jars were only for the dragonpit.

Comment: Which is why we can conclude that most of the caches are intact because we know of only one such discovery. But Hallayne says **another cache was found** so it means the order had been discovering other caches as well but it appears they were not so numerous which is why it did not raise suspicion among the order and they did not notify the government. At least not that we know of

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I do not think we know exactly what number was Tyrion expecting but it appears his estimate was way far below 13000. Which is why he was just shocked by the numbers and refused to believe them. Crown has to pay the order of course. Tyrion was nothing if not efficient, he would never pay for false goods.

Comment: Yeah, he comes across that way in the show, too. (I haven't read the books.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## No

Tyrion appears to have used all of the wildfire he found for the Battle of Blackwater. However, it appears as though he didn't find all of the caches of wildfire that Aerys had hid around the city as [@Aegon's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/132506/58193) explores in more detail.

In Season 6 Episode 10, "The Winds of Winter", Cersei and Qyburn use some wildfire to create some nice fireworks for the amusement of the residents of Flea Bottom.

> [image: Baelor explosion]

This is actually alluded to in episode 8 with Qyburn and Cersei having the following conversation.

> Qyburn: Your Grace...that old rumor you told me about. My little birds investigated.
>   Cersei: And? Was it just a rumor or something more?
>   Qyburn: More. Much more.
>   <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 6 Episode 8, "No One"</sub>

Comment: I think their speech refers to wildfire left after the mad king. Tyrion may have used all the wildfire he had at that time.

Comment: @C.Koca The question is asking did Tyrion use all of Aerys' wildfire cache, at least that's my interpretation of it. As such my answer is no but I do agree with you that Tyrion probably used all he could find.